# redefine ~ only within the scope of a \newcommand

Tags: macros, catcodes, tilde, scoping

I'd like to create a command (`\newcommand`) that does some decoration around a text (basically drawing a box around the text), for technical reports:

Eg like:

```
  Use \pdobj{frob}{noz zle} for achievers
```

renders like:

[image]

Now the argument text (in this case `frob` and `noz zle`) very commonly uses the tilde-symbol `~`.
Since tilde is obviously special,  I currently have to use

```
And \pdobj{slurp$\sim$}{} they did.
```

to achieve:

[image]

Now, what I would really like to do is to simply write

```
And \pdobj{slurp~}{} they did.
```

for the same effect.
As far as I understand this would require to re-define the `~` command, with something like

```
\def~{$\sim$}
```

While this seems to work, it also makes the traditional use of `~` as a non-breaking space (outside of my command) impossible.

However, the `\url` command somehow does the trick to render `~` as some special glyphs (e.g. `\url{~T}`) without affecting the NBSP-use outside its scope.

I had a looked at `url.sty`, but frankly, this is way beyond my TeX-foo.

So, is there are (simple/easy/straightforward) way to make `~` do something completely different when encountered inside an argument to my command vs outside?

Comment: \catcode`~=12  will then allow you to \def~{$\sim$}.  Note that it will render other uses of ~ defunct, unless you limit its scope.  The key, however, is to redefine the catcode *before* you absorb the argument containing the tilde.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes you can't redefine `~` when it has catcode *other*. But I guess you actually know that :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just redefine `~` in a group

```
\newcommand{\pdobj}[2]{%
  \begingroup\def~{$\sim$}%
  <the other code for boxing the material
  \endgroup
}
```

With the current definition of `\pdobj`, the code can be better optimized.

Comment: perfect. so simple...